# Reset password / recreate outer volume in TrueCrypt

Tags: truecrypt

Is there any way to reset password for outer volume and recreate it without loosing hidden volume?

Comment: What does the Truecrypt documentation say?

Comment: I didn't find anything about re-creation of outer volume only. The only way seems to be to move data to some storage and create everything from scratch, which I'd like to avoid.